# how to create a custom table in netsuite?

Tags: mysql, database, netsuite

I am using netsuite builder for creating a website. I want to create a mysql table in it but it does not allow me to do so. Please suggest how to create custom mysql table in netsuite database.

Comment: whats the error message

Comment: There is no error message as I am not able to find from where I create the table.

Comment: From the admin role, in the Custom tab, they call it custom records.

Answer (score 2):

In the admin role, go to the menu
Customization>List,Records & Fields>Record Types> New

Give it a name and ID, alongwith any other options. Save the record. Once the record has been saved, it gives you the option to add fields to the record.

Note: this would be a NetSuite table or to be precise - Custom Record Type.

Comment: how can we read that records value in coding file.. dynamicaly.. pls suggest available functions

Comment: You have two options - either use Suitetalk, or use Suitescript. In SuiteScript, you have API calls such as nlapiLoadRecord(...) that can help you read those record, or nlapiSearchRecord(..)  to search.

Comment: Also see; https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/40831/ for a sample script that accesses custom records through script (note, you will need to be logged in through NetSuite to access SuiteAnswers)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the NetSuite account, you can create custom records.

Comment: Yes, I have access to the Netsuite account, please elaborate How can I create custom records